# How to change a Textfield into a Select list in a Views Exposed Filter

Tags: 8

Figured this question would be asked before, but don't see it.

I have a views exposed filter with a Text Field as one of the filters. I'd like to display this filter as a Select List instead of the standard text input or autocomplete.

Any advice on how to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, figured out a solid solution using hook_form_alter.

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    
    if ($form['#id'] == 'EXPOSED-FORM-ID') {
    
        $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','CONTENTTYPE')->execute();
        $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
        $options = ['' => 'All'];
    
        foreach($nodes as $nid => $node) {
          $value = $node->get('FIELD_NAME')->getString();
    
          if (isset($value)) {
            $options[$value] = $value;
          }
        }
    
        if (isset($form['FIELD_NAME_value'])) {
          $form['FIELD_NAME_value']['#type'] = 'select';
          $form['FIELD_NAME_value']['#options'] = $options;
          $form['FIELD_NAME_value']['#size'] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yuckle :)

Comment: Consider using the more specific hook `MODULENAME_form_views_exposed_form_alter()`

Answer (score 1):

You can Implement using `hook_form_alter`

```
//Note: This will apply to all Views (thoes having same textfield in exposed filter).

function moduleName_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, &$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    
    // Replace your TextField Name with 'field1'
    $form['field1'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',  // Converting to select list
      '#options' => array(0 => t('<any>'), 20 => '*', 40 => '**', 60 => '***', 80 => '****', 100 => '*****'),  // your options/array
      '#default_value' => 0,
      '#title' => t('The average vote is more than'),
    );
  }
}
```

if you want to implement for specific view only then try following code.

```
function moduleName_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, &$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {

    $view = $form_state->get('view');
//    \Drupal::logger('$view')->notice('<pre><code>' . print_r($view, TRUE) . '</code></pre>' );
    
    if ($view->id() == 'your_view_name') {

      // Replace your TextField Name with 'field1'
      $form['field1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select', // Converting to select list
        '#options' => array(0 => t('<any>'), 20 => '*', 40 => '**', 60 => '***', 80 => '****', 100 => '*****'), // your options/array
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#title' => t('The average vote is more than'),
      );
    }
  }
}
```